# SQL Query to order by with case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

Hi here I'm trying to put order by based on case. Here is my trail and I'm getting syntax error at 'END'

Can someone tell me whats wrong in this?

```
CREATE TABLE [Emp](
    [Id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
insert into emp values ('01','one')
insert into emp values ('02','Two')
insert into emp values ('3','Three')
insert into emp values ('10','Ten')
insert into emp values ('01A','oneA')
insert into emp values ('*','Star')
go
declare @sortby varchar(100)
set @sortby = 'Id'
select * from emp

ORDER BY 
    CASE @sortby
      WHEN 'Id' THEN 
         CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Id)=1 
                THEN CAST(Id as int)
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) > 1 
                THEN CAST(LEFT(Id,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) - 1) as int)
            ELSE 2147483648
        END
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Id)=1 
                THEN NULL
            WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) > 1 
                THEN SUBSTRING(Id,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',Id) ,50) 
            ELSE Id
        END 
    END,
    Name
```

Comment: You need an `else` before the second `case`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. It is working now :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there any way to display special character to come first in the result? In the above example I'm expecting * (star) to come first in the result

Comment: @vkp . . . Why did you delete your answer?  It looked correct to me.